# Unicode <input> value appears differently between browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode

I'm using jQuery to set a text input's value to a string of unicode chars (it repro's with vanilla js):

```js
$(function() {  
    var value = "\u0000J\u0000o\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000J\u0000e\u0000t\u0000t\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000T\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000B\u0000l\u0000a\u0000c\u0000k\u0000h\u0000e\u0000a\u0000r\u0000t\u0000s\u0000";

    var $input = $('<input type="text" style="width: 200px;"></input>').val(value);

    $('body').html($input);
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tested against the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and all three behave differently, with Chrome behaving the most desirably:

**Chrome 50.0:**

[image: Chrome]

**Safari 9.1.1:**

[image: Safari]

**Firefox 46.0**

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Have you tried `value = decodeURIComponent(value)`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Putting control characters in a form field seems not really valid...

Comment: Just asking the obvious question: If that Chrome screenshot is the desirable result, why don't you just set it to `"Joan Jett and The Blackhearts"`? (or: why do you need `NUL` characters in that field?)

Comment: @roeland It's user-generated content.

Comment: @Emmett Then you're doing something wrong with it, probably you're decoding UTF-16-encoded data with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can `<pre>` element with `contentEditable` attribute set, `css` `appearance` set to `textfield`, `:focus` to apply `<input>` element `:focus` styles at `focus` on `<pre>` element

```js
var value = "\u0000J\u0000o\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000J\u0000e\u0000t\u0000t\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000T\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000B\u0000l\u0000a\u0000c\u0000k\u0000h\u0000e\u0000a\u0000r\u0000t\u0000s\u0000";
var text = $("<pre>", {
  text: value,
  contentEditable: true,
  class:"input"
});
$("body").append(text);
```

```css
pre.input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #A8A8A8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:13.3333px;
}
pre.input:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  outline-style: none;
  border-color:dodgerblue;
  border-width:2px;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  box-shadow:.025em .025em .025em dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" value="Joan Jett and The Blackhearts" />
<!-- compare appended `<pre>` element -->
```